# Как сделать, чтобы Bootstrap Popovers всегда был в пределах экрана?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

При использовании Bootstrap Popovers столкнулся с проблемой:
Всплывающее окошко вылезает за экран.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С правой стороны ещё хуже: окошко не появляется, при этом дёргается экран.
Реально ли сделать какое-то автоцентрирование, чтобы скрипт сам рассчитывал, как расположить popover в зависимости от экрана?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать атрибут `data-placement`. Для автоматического позиционирования может подойти значение `auto`.

Взято с [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp):

> **Positioning Popovers**
>
> By default, the popover will appear on the right side of the element.
>
> Use the `data-placement` attribute to set the position of the popover on
>   top, bottom, left or the right side of the element:
>
> ```
> <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Content">Click</a>
> <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Content">Click</a>
> <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Content">Click</a>
> <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Content">Click</a>
> ```
>
> - *Tip: You can also use the data-placement attribute with a value of "auto", which will let the browser decide the position of the popover.
>     For example, if the value is "auto left", the popover will display on
>     the left side when possible, otherwise on the right.*

Comment: К сожалению данный способ не работает, в хроме так точно. А жаль, было бы идеальное решение.